# How To apply CSS To a jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),
    new Date().getDate());
  $('#startdate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    maxDate: function() {
      return $('#enddate').val();

    }
  });
  $('#enddate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    minDate: function() {
      return $('#startdate').val();
    },

  });

  $("#areaFormID").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentlyClickedOutlet = $("#myselect").find(":selected")[0].textContent;
    var currentlyClickedStartdate = $("#startdate").val();
    var currentlyClickedenddate = $("#enddate").val();
    var displayDates = ("For the date between  '" + currentlyClickedStartdate + "'  To  '" + currentlyClickedenddate + "' and Outlet  '" + currentlyClickedOutlet + "'");
    $("#fromDatetoDate").html(displayDates);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="fromDatetoDate"></div>
<!--  this one to show dates  -->
<form id="areaFormID" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">

      <option>ALL</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have a date field and one select field whose values I am storing in a variable after user selects some values. I am then displaying them into a div container.

What I am trying to do is :

- I am trying to apply some `css styling` to them.

After running the code I get **For the date between '05/01/2019' To '11/01/2019' and Outlet 'ALL'** this line

- I want to style dates and outlet with some color and make them bold.
- E.g. For the date between **'05/01/2019'** To **'11/01/2019'** and Outlet **'ALL'**
- I just don't know how to add css to jquery variables

So any kind of guidance would be helpful.

Comment: in which selectors do you want to add css using jquery??

Comment: @Sushil the example i have given i want to do like that  E.g. For the date between **'05/01/2019'**  To **'11/01/2019'** and Outlet  **'ALL'**

Comment: You can't style some arbitrary characters in the element's text content, you have to wrap those parts with a suitable elements.

Comment: wrap it with `<strong> ` tag or wrap  and add `class` attribute and add `CSS` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to just use `strong` tags:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),
    new Date().getDate());
  $('#startdate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    maxDate: function() {
      return $('#enddate').val();

    }
  });
  $('#enddate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    minDate: function() {
      return $('#startdate').val();
    },

  });

  $("#areaFormID").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentlyClickedOutlet = $("#myselect").find(":selected")[0].textContent;
    var currentlyClickedStartdate = $("#startdate").val();
    var currentlyClickedenddate = $("#enddate").val();
    var displayDates = ("For the date between  <strong>'" + currentlyClickedStartdate + "'</strong>  to  <strong>'" + currentlyClickedenddate + "'</strong> and Outlet <strong>'" + currentlyClickedOutlet + "'</strong>");
    $("#fromDatetoDate").html(displayDates);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="fromDatetoDate"></div>
<!--  this one to show dates  -->
<form id="areaFormID" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">

      <option>ALL</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you want to do it via css:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),
    new Date().getDate());
  $('#startdate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    maxDate: function() {
      return $('#enddate').val();

    }
  });
  $('#enddate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    minDate: function() {
      return $('#startdate').val();
    },

  });

  $("#areaFormID").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentlyClickedOutlet = $("#myselect").find(":selected")[0].textContent;
    var currentlyClickedStartdate = $("#startdate").val();
    var currentlyClickedenddate = $("#enddate").val();
    var displayDates = ("For the date between  <span>'" + currentlyClickedStartdate + "'</span>  to  <span>'" + currentlyClickedenddate + "'</span> and Outlet <span>'" + currentlyClickedOutlet + "'</span>");
    $("#fromDatetoDate").html(displayDates);
  });
});
```

```css
#fromDatetoDate span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="fromDatetoDate"></div>
<!--  this one to show dates  -->
<form id="areaFormID" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">

      <option>ALL</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ok this one is cool..but what if i want to add some css like styling them with color and all

Comment: Updated my answer with a `css` version

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your date and Outlet with `span` and give them class like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),
    new Date().getDate());
  $('#startdate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    maxDate: function() {
      return $('#enddate').val();

    }
  });
  $('#enddate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    minDate: function() {
      return $('#startdate').val();
    },

  });

  $("#areaFormID").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentlyClickedOutlet = $("#myselect").find(":selected")[0].textContent;
    var currentlyClickedStartdate = $("#startdate").val();
    var currentlyClickedenddate = $("#enddate").val();
    var displayDates = ("For the date between  '" + "<span class='bold'>" + currentlyClickedStartdate + "</span>" + "'  To  '" + "<span class='bold'>" + currentlyClickedenddate + "</span>" + "' and Outlet  '" + "<span class='bold'>" + currentlyClickedOutlet + "</span>" + "'");
    $("#fromDatetoDate").html(displayDates);
  });
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="fromDatetoDate"></div>
<!--  this one to show dates  -->
<form id="areaFormID" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">

      <option>ALL</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

check below code. hope this solves your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),
    new Date().getDate());
  $('#startdate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    maxDate: function() {
      return $('#enddate').val();

    }
  });
  $('#enddate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    minDate: function() {
      return $('#startdate').val();
    },

  });

  $("#areaFormID").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentlyClickedOutlet = $("#myselect").find(":selected")[0].textContent;
    var currentlyClickedStartdate = $("#startdate").val();
    var currentlyClickedenddate = $("#enddate").val();
    var displayDates = ("For the date between <span class='date'> '" + currentlyClickedStartdate + "'</span>  To  <span class='date'>'" + currentlyClickedenddate + "'</span> and Outlet  <span class='date'>'" + currentlyClickedOutlet + "'</span>");
    $("#fromDatetoDate").html(displayDates);
  });
});
```

```css
.date{
font-weight:bold;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="fromDatetoDate"></div>
<!--  this one to show dates  -->
<form id="areaFormID" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">

      <option>ALL</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer would be improved with an explanation of your approach to the problem

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery .html(htmlString)** accepts a string of HTML.

In reference to the example while constructing displayDates keyword, it can be constructed as a HTML string. Wrap it in a strong tag or a span tag and apply styles.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),
    new Date().getDate());
  $('#startdate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    maxDate: function() {
      return $('#enddate').val();

    }
  });
  $('#enddate').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

    minDate: function() {
      return $('#startdate').val();
    },

  });

  $("#areaFormID").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentlyClickedOutlet = $("#myselect").find(":selected")[0].textContent;
    var currentlyClickedStartdate = $("#startdate").val();
    var currentlyClickedenddate = $("#enddate").val();
    var displayDates = ("For the date between  <span class='bold highlight'>'" + currentlyClickedStartdate + "'</span>  To  <span class='bold highlight'>'" + currentlyClickedenddate + "'</span> and Outlet  <span class='bold highlight'>'" + currentlyClickedOutlet + "'</span>");
    $("#fromDatetoDate").html(displayDates);
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: #66a95b;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="fromDatetoDate"></div>
<!--  this one to show dates  -->
<form id="areaFormID" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">

      <option>ALL</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```